# Is it possible to apply list_filters for parent's object's fields in django?

Tags: python, django

I want to display the timestamp stored in my parents model to be shown in my model. Also, I want to display it in german format. This is not the problem, but of course I want to be able to sort by this timestamp.

One solution would be to create a new DateTimeField in model B, but then I would store redundant information. How can I do that with Django?

For example:

```
#models.py
class A(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

class B(models.Model):
    key_to_a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

##########

#admin.py
class BAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def german_timestamp(self, B):
        return B.key_to_a.timestamp.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

    german_timestamp.short_description = "timestamp"

    list_display = ("german_timestamp")
    list_filter = ("german_timestamp") #This breaks my code as there is no field called "german_timestamp"
```

Answer (score -1):

I cannot post a comment, which is maybe is the case, but:

Have you tried to set a `__str__` method in your A model? Or a `german_timestamp` method in the A model (if you plan to use other formats for your date) that returns A.timestamp in the format you want.

This way you could just set key_to_a in your list_filter and it will use the method of the A model.